# Java - How to parse JSON and CSV files in Java and store them in Neo4j Database

Tags: java, neo4j, nosql, graph-databases

**Current Situation:** I have two files, one in JSON format and the other in CSV format. I would like to parse them in Java and store the results in a Neo4j DB for later use.

**What I have till now:** I have used Jackson Library to parse the JSON file and for the CSV file I have done as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CSVReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String csvFile = "path/to/file/data.csv";
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {


                String[] dataPoints = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                System.out.println("Data [point1= " + dataPoints[4] + " , point3=" + dataPoints[3] + "]");

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Problem:** I can display the results fine but I would like to store them in a Neo4j Database. I don't know how to proceed with that. Can anyone help or point me to the right direction? 
I just started with Neo4j so some extra clarification regarding the code/steps would be really helpful.

EDIT: For example, with MySQL I would do something like this to insert values into a table.

```
String query = " insert into users (first_name, last_name, dob, email_id)"
        + " values (?, ?, ?, ?)";

      // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
      PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

      // code to set values

      // execute the preparedstatement
      preparedStmt.execute();
```

What would be the equivalent in Neo4J?

Note: Downvoting a question without explaining what is wrong with it doesn't really achieve anything. There's criticism and then there's constructive criticism. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to parse CSV in Java if you are not transforming it. You can load the csv using Cypher query and it will be simple and faster. If you are processing it in Java then it's fine.

Comment: I edited the question to provide some clarification as to what I want to do. I understand your point regarding parsing CSV. How can I use Cypher query to load it and persist it in the database?

Comment: Okay, I am sharing the link here which would be helpful to load data with cypher query: https://neo4j.com/graphgist/importing-csv-files-with-cypher

Comment: BTW It's not me who downvoted your question!

Comment: I checked the link. My scenario is that my application is in Java and I need a way to parse files (CSV and JSON) and persist them in Neo4j. I mentioned the *SQL way* to do it in the edit. I want to know how to do it for Neo4j.

Comment: My comment about the downvote was a general one, not for anyone particularly. Downvoting without explaining what is wrong with the question or how it could be improved doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to find out how to interact with a database in Java? The native way is via JDBC, but there are other options. The Neo4J JDBC driver documentation (https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-jdbc-driver-3-3-1-release/) has some good pointers on how to proceed. 
As to parsing, the CSV parsing code you have here looks good and the Jackson library is a fine option for parsing JSON. 
Can you elaborate on what you're looking for?

Comment: I provided some clarification in the question as to what my objective is.Thanks for the link. This is definitely a starting point!

Comment: Hello, I found this link which may help you out some more:
https://markhneedham.com/blog/2013/06/20/neo4j-a-simple-example-using-the-jdbc-driver/